# how to access a file in the root of the android project, java path

Tags: java, android

I have a configuration folder in the root of my android project and a file in side this project i need to access from a class deep inside the project. the directory structure is like this:
myProject/config/config.properties
myProject/src/com/testProject/util/Configuration.java

form the Config.java I need to read config.properties
I have tries with the following code:

```
InputStream stream = Configuration.class.getResourceAsStream("../../../../config/config.properties");
```

but the stream variable is null meaning the pat is wrong.
Can some one please send me the correct relative path to the config properties file searching from the Config.java file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is tricky accessing the a resource from the project since after the .apk is build the local file system on the phone is accessed and not the  project files. My solution is putting the files that I need to access in the project/assets file and then they can be acesed ussin the getAssets() method. So the path is like this:

```
myProject/assets/config.properties 
myProject/src/com/testProject/util/Configuration.java
```

and the code inside Configuration.java is:

```
AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
stream = manager.open("config/config.properties");
```

So the important thing is that only files inside the assets folder can be accessed, and also you need a context to call the getAssets() method.