# Android FileInputStream FileNotFound in Eclipse

Tags: android, io, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I've created an xml file at the root of my project (Player.xml).  I have added the uses-permission tags in the AndroidManifest.xml.  I feel like I have tried everything and still get the FileNotFoundException.
My code in the onCreate() method:

```
 try {

     String newFile = "/TTBossUI/Player.xml";
        FileInputStream inputStream7;
        File f = new File(newFile);
        System.out.println("made it to pos #1");
        inputStream7 = new FileInputStream(f);
        System.out.println("made it to pos #2");
        inputStream7.close();
        System.out.println("made it to pos #3");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("file not found:" + fnfe);
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I never make it past the "made it to pos #1", goes straight to the catch block.
I have tried every possible file/filepath string.
I have this working perfectly in a java only (non-android) application.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error you're receiving? Share logcat pls

Comment: This is the pertinent info from LogCat:   made it to pos #1

08-15 13:08:26.049: I/System.out(797): file not found: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /TTBossUI/Player.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: made it to pos #1

08-15 13:08:26.049: I/System.out(797): file not found: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /TTBossUI/Player.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Please: never post log output or code in comments! Edit the question instead and add the information there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the log points out, no such file exists. This is probably because you're using a relative filepath and not an absolute one. The `File f` is also probably null.

A resource file shouldn't be saved in the root of your project but rather saved as Android wants resources to be saved, i.e in the res / assets folder. For more information on this read https://stackoverflow.com/a/17446587/2707325.

Depending on what will be stored in this `Player.xml` file, you can use different ways to store data or retrieve settings. I'd suggest a database for saving data; and either gradle flavors, a static java class, or shared preferences for saving configurations.

Comment: I did try to place the xml file in the res folder but that gave me errors on other lines such as this:     textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  The "R" was underlined and the error was "R cannot be resolved to a variable".  I was going to use the xml file to serialize an array.

Comment: Well the res folder only accepts files in a certain structure, because Android doesnt give you direct access to them. But rather ways to access data in them. But if that's all you've got from what i've wrote then it looks like this will be a long journey. The main thing here, and my main question is, what are you going to use this xml file for?

Comment: I have an array of objects that I want to serialize into the xml file with an ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: Then create it via code in the application context so you can later access it.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate your help.  I will look into this.

Comment: `dit try to place the xml file in the res folder`. Bad idea. Put it in the assets folder instead. And use assetsManager to open an inputstream to your file. FileInputStream cannot be used. Just google for reading files from assets.